# Javafx detachable pane system

Tags: java, javafx

This is something I like that I have seen in a few different softwares. I don't know where it originates from or what it really is called but here is an example of the pane system in Visual Studio.

[image]

Note how I can easily attach the pane anywhere with ease. Is such a thing possible with Javafx?

Comment: See https://github.com/panemu/tiwulfx-dock for a viable solution and see https://github.com/DaveJarvis/PitchDockFX#requirements for a review of frameworks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recognize this question is old but others may be interested to know. I created a lightweight docking library for JavaFX for both proprietary and non-proprietary uses under the LGPL license.

https://github.com/RobertBColton/DockFX

[image]

Comment: I just looked at this today, unfortunately it does not build out of the box.

Comment: There is actually already an available release. The project uses Apache Maven for building releases, but I also kept a jar description to export from Eclipse. If you need anymore help feel free to post an issue or ask here and I will try to help.
https://github.com/RobertBColton/DockFX/releases

Comment: Hi, the page on git hub mentions full documentation but I can't see it there.  Am I looking in  the wrong place?

Comment: Hi Rob, it's actually in the source code and I use the format that will show up in Eclipse's code completion. However, I didn't run a document processor on it yet so I have not uploaded them yet, but that is on my todo list. Full documentation means that the source code is fully documented. I'm sorry about the confusion.

Comment: That sounds good enough, I assume you mean Javadoc format?  I'll have a look at it properly this weekend.  Cheers

Answer (score 7):

There is no built-in docking framework for JavaFX 8.

There are some 3rd party solutions such as [Drombler FX](http://sourceforge.net/p/drombler/wiki/DockingFramework/).  I haven't used any of them.

A simple home-built system to dock and undock panels is pretty easy to create, but a comprehensive system would be quite difficult.  The following code is adapted from zonski's answer to a docking framework discussion is in the [Oracle JavaFX forum threads](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2308839).

[image: docked]
[image: undocked]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class SimpleDocking extends Application {
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final SplitPane rootPane = new SplitPane();
        rootPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

        final FlowPane dockedArea = new FlowPane();
        dockedArea.getChildren().add(new Label("Some docked content"));

        final FlowPane centerArea = new FlowPane();
        final Button undockButton = new Button("Undock");
        centerArea.getChildren().add(undockButton);

        rootPane.getItems().addAll(centerArea, dockedArea);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(rootPane, 300, 300));
        stage.show();

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(stage);
        undockButton.disableProperty().bind(dialog.showingProperty());
        undockButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            rootPane.getItems().remove(dockedArea);

            dialog.setOnHidden(windowEvent -> {
                rootPane.getItems().add(dockedArea);
            });
            dialog.setContent(dockedArea);
            dialog.show(stage);
        });
    }

    private class Dialog extends Popup {
        private BorderPane root;

        private Dialog(Window parent) {
            root = new BorderPane();
            root.setPrefSize(200, 200);
            root.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 1; -fx-border-color: gray");
            root.setTop(buildTitleBar());
            setX(parent.getX() + 50);
            setY(parent.getY() + 50);
            getContent().add(root);
        }

        public void setContent(Node content) {
            root.setCenter(content);
        }

        private Node buildTitleBar() {
            BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
            pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: burlywood; -fx-padding: 5");

            final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
            pane.setOnMousePressed(mouseEvent -> {
                dragDelta.x = getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
                dragDelta.y = getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
            });
            pane.setOnMouseDragged(mouseEvent -> {
                setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x);
                setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
            });

            Label title = new Label("My Dialog");
            title.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: midnightblue;");
            pane.setLeft(title);

            Button closeButton = new Button("X");
            closeButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> hide());
            pane.setRight(closeButton);

            return pane;
        }
    }

    private static class Delta {
        double x, y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you have *extensive* need for such a framework, you might want to look into the [NetBeans platform](https://netbeans.org/features/platform/features.html), which is a Swing based framework into which you can embed JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

A simple docking framework for JavaFX:

https://github.com/andy-goryachev/FxDock

```
public void start(Stage s) throws Exception
{
    // plug in custom windows and dockable panes. 
    FxDockFramework.setGenerator(new DemoPanes());

    // load saved layout
    int ct = FxDockFramework.loadLayout();
    if(ct == 0)
    {
        // when no saved layout exists, open the first window
        DemoWindow.openBrowser("https://github.com/andy-goryachev/FxDock");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22433484/1879990) says, JavaFX does not have built-in support for dockable tabs. There is an [OpenJDK issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092098) requesting support for draggable and dockable tabs.

A recent third-party solution that may be worth looking into is [DockFX](https://github.com/RobertBColton/DockFX) which is in active development at the time of writing (September 2015)