# JavaFX- Floating menu

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create a detachable floating toolbar menu with the JavaFX. But the problem is I don't know the exact name for this kind of menu.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a [ribbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_(computing)).  There is a third party library for ribbons, you could try out: [FXRibbon](https://github.com/dukke/FXRibbon).

To make the ribbon detachable, you could use:

- [Javafx detachable pane system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432811/javafx-detachable-pane-system)

Comment: Thanks,  this is very helpful.